# terraform call a module in a loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to call a terraform module with for_each function from another resource, data, local etc?

terraform required_version = ">= 0.15.4"

---

def.tfvar

```
name                         = "app-stage"
project                      = "stage-xyz"
```

main.tf

```
    source             = "../../src/codedeploy"
    name               = var.name
    project            = var.project
    s3_bucket_arn      = var.s3_bucket_arn
    environment        = var.environment
    app_name           = module.codedeploy.app_name
```

output.tf

```
output "app_name" {
  value = aws_codedeploy_app.app.name
}
```

this one **works**, but if I wanted to create several codedeploy then I have to create several tfvar files and apply them. Instead of doing that, I would like to create one tfvar file and use for_each function within the main.tf file.

---

abce.tfvar

```
codeDeploy_records = {
  "app-stage= {
      project                      = "stage-xyz",
    },
  "app-qa= {
      project                      = "qa-xyz",
   }
  }
```

main.tf

```
module "codedeploy" {
   
    for_each    = var.codeDeploy_records
        source             = "../../src/codedeploy"
        name               = each.key
        project            = each.value.project
        app_name           = module.codedeploy.app_name
```

that one gives the below **error**.
This object does not have an attribute named "app_name".

Can we call a module from like below?

```
local test {
for_each    = var.codeDeploy_records
        source             = "../../src/codedeploy"
        name               = each.key
        project            = each.value.projec
        app_name           = module.codedeploy.app_name 

}

module "codedeploy" {
```

Comment: I double checked my previous answer, and yes, you can do this. Sorry, I was wrong, you were right. Nevertheless, fully working example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

the solution for me in this case

```
app_name           = module.codedeploy_app[each.key].app_name
```